# Making USB devices writeable for users other than root

Tags: usb-drive, automounting

I have a USB device, formatted FAT32 (for the widest possible compatibility), plugged into a system running CentOS 5 (yes, I know it's antiquated).

The whole purpose of its being plugged in is to receive backup files sent from two other systems.

But because (apparently) of UDEV default behavior, it mounts (along with its subdirectories) as "drwxr-xr-x 5 root root," refusing to accept anything sent to it, and refusing any "chown" (with an error message) or "chmod" (quietly failing).

Is there a way to change the default mounting behavior for USB FAT32 devices?
I will note that /etc/udev/rules.d on this box contains:

```
05-udev-early.rules  60-pcmcia.rules         90-alsa.rules
40-multipath.rules   60-raw.rules            90-dm.rules
50-udev.rules        60-wacom.rules          90-hal.rules
51-hotplug.rules     61-uinput-stddev.rules  95-pam-console.rules
60-libsane.rules     61-uinput-wacom.rules   98-kexec.rules
60-net.rules         85-pcscd_ccid.rules     bluetooth.rules
```

Note that the object here is to *specifically avoid* having to explicitly mount the bloody thing (and to *not* have to add a new fstab entry every time we plug in a different device)!

I've found "udevmonitor" (no "udevadm"), and when I plug the device in:

```
UEVENT[1618003563.847325] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5
UEVENT[1618003563.847392] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/usbdev1.4_ep00
UEVENT[1618003563.849089] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0
UEVENT[1618003563.849130] add@/class/scsi_host/host4
UEVENT[1618003563.849155] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/usbdev1.4_ep8b
UEVENT[1618003563.849180] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/usbdev1.4_ep0a
UEVENT[1618003563.849203] add@/class/usb_device/usbdev1.4
UDEV  [1618003563.850150] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5
UDEV  [1618003564.062789] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/usbdev1.4_ep00
UDEV  [1618003564.186813] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0
UDEV  [1618003564.298705] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/usbdev1.4_ep8b
UDEV  [1618003564.298769] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/usbdev1.4_ep0a
UDEV  [1618003564.308695] add@/class/scsi_host/host4
UDEV  [1618003564.614084] add@/class/usb_device/usbdev1.4
UEVENT[1618003569.124366] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0
UEVENT[1618003569.124416] add@/class/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0
UEVENT[1618003569.179432] add@/block/sda
UEVENT[1618003569.179466] add@/block/sda/sda1
UEVENT[1618003569.179485] add@/block/sda/sda2
UEVENT[1618003569.179508] add@/class/scsi_device/4:0:0:0
UEVENT[1618003569.179612] add@/class/scsi_generic/sg0
UDEV  [1618003569.290405] add@/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0
UDEV  [1618003569.423752] add@/class/scsi_generic/sg0
UDEV  [1618003569.423806] add@/class/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0
UDEV  [1618003569.474344] add@/class/scsi_device/4:0:0:0
UDEV  [1618003569.505476] add@/block/sda
UDEV  [1618003569.861895] add@/block/sda/sda1
UDEV  [1618003569.919434] add@/block/sda/sda2
UEVENT[1618003570.253329] mount@/block/sda/sda2
UDEV  [1618003570.254399] mount@/block/sda/sda2
```

A udevinfo -p /block/sda/sda2 -q all gives me:

```
P: /block/sda/sda2
N: sda2
S: disk/by-id/usb-Seagate_BUP_Slim_BK_NA7LFNNT-part2
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part2
S: disk/by-uuid/6D63-17F2
S: disk/by-label/BACKUP
E: ID_VENDOR=Seagate
E: ID_MODEL=BUP_Slim_BK
E: ID_REVISION=0143
E: ID_SERIAL=Seagate_BUP_Slim_BK_NA7LFNNT
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:5:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_FS_USAGE=filesystem
E: ID_FS_TYPE=vfat
E: ID_FS_VERSION=FAT32
E: ID_FS_UUID=6D63-17F2
E: ID_FS_LABEL=BACKUP
E: ID_FS_LABEL_SAFE=BACKUP
```

and a udevinfo -p /block/sda2 -1 gives me:

```
  looking at device '/block/sda/sda2':
    KERNEL=="sda2"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    SYSFS{stat}=="      38      329      661      163        1        1        2        4        0      139      167"
    SYSFS{size}=="1952849920"
    SYSFS{start}=="411648"
    SYSFS{dev}=="8:2"

  looking at parent device '/block/sda':
    ID=="sda"
    BUS=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    SYSFS{stat}=="     112     1237     1811      361        1        1        2        4        0      241      365"
    SYSFS{size}=="1953525167"
    SYSFS{removable}=="0"
    SYSFS{range}=="16"
    SYSFS{dev}=="8:0"
. . .
```

I tried going into /etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules, and changing

```
# all block devices
SUBSYSTEM=="block",             GROUP="disk", MODE="0640"
KERNEL=="root",                 GROUP="disk", MODE="0640"
```

to

```
# all block devices
SUBSYSTEM=="block",             GROUP="disk", MODE="0660"
KERNEL=="root",                 GROUP="disk", MODE="0640"
```

and rebooting; no effect

Further down I found this (AFTER "persistent_end"):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", \
        PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'K=%k; K=$${K#usbdev}; printf bus/usb/%%03i/%%03i $${K%%%%.*} $${K#*.}'", \
        NAME="%c", MODE="0644"
```

and tried changing 644 to 664; also no effect (and besides, the subsystem is supposed to be "block").

Is there someplace else I could put something to specify a MODE parameter that would open USB device access up?

I noticed the

```
UEVENT[1618003570.253329] mount@/block/sda/sda2
UDEV  [1618003570.254399] mount@/block/sda/sda2
```

at the bottom of the udevmonitor output. I note that a grep on "mount" doesn't find a single rule responding to a "mount" event. Is there something I could add, that would respond to this, either changing the mount parameters or remounting the device?

Answer (score 1):

`chown` and `chmod` doesn't work as FAT doesn't implement them, but when mounting, you can specify `umask` to allow everybody to wite to it or `uid` to set owner of everything on the flashdrive. If you are talking about ability to mount it, you can add entry into `/etc/fstab` with appropriate options and `users`. I guess with CentOS 5, you don't have that many things connecting to the device to warrant anything more complex then static `fstab`.

Comment: Right, but how do either of those options affect how it automounts? The whole point is to avoid having to explicitly mount it every time it's plugged in.

Comment: If you add correct `uid` and `umask` options to whatever is automounting your flashdrive, it should help. Alternatively, you can easily mount it manually with users option in fstab. Depends how do you do the automounting and whether you really need it.

Comment: udev is almost certainly what's doing the automounting. And I've added all I could find so far about the details of that process to the question

Comment: _udev_ by itself doesn't do any auto-mounting, it just creates/manages devices. You can add `RUN` option to mount, but most likely it is something else that handles automounting for you, either autofs, udisk or something even older. But there is a chance that if you add a static entry into fstab with options, disk and directory where to mount it, those deamons might pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automount using `udev` you can add something like this to your udev rules:

```
# Symlinks

SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?",       ACTION=="add",    PROGRAM="/etc/udev/scripts/isremovable.sh %k", RESULT=="YES", SYMLINK="usb_flash_raw", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh %k"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?[0-9]*", ACTION=="add",    PROGRAM="/etc/udev/scripts/isremovable.sh %k", RESULT=="YES", SYMLINK="usb_flash_p%n", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/mount.sh %k"

# umount

SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd?",       ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/etc/udev/scripts/umount.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null"
```

Where the is removable can be something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
DEV="`basename "$1" | sed 's|[0-9]*$||'`"
if [ "`find /sys -name "$DEV" | grep usb`" ]; then
        echo "YES"
        exit 0
else
        echo "NO"
        exit 1
fi
```

And the mount/umount scripts can be whatever you want, but be aware that handling safe unmounting is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately took a different approach.

I set up a cron job, running every five minutes, to transfer files uploaded to the backup users' home directories over to the USB drives, under root authority, and to keep them from transferring before the upload is complete, I have the upload client set up to send the files without an extension, then rename them to add the extension once the upload is complete.

Then I discovered that signing off the console unmounts the USB device. So much for using udev-based automounting.

So since the cron job's script was already present, I set up my own mountpoint, then added code to see if a properly set up USB device is present at the mountpoint, and if not, it attempts to mount the device.

Then I found the first pleasant surprise of this whole exercise: while mounting the device at my mountpoint keeps it from showing up under /media, it somehow does *not* stop Gnome from making it available on the desktop when I sign on.